# play offline M3U8 video file in meteor/cordova app in android

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, video

I'm totally stuck trying to get local video content to play in a meteor/cordova app.

The reason for this is we need our meteor app to support offline mode for a user-selectable subset of the data, including videos. When the user goes offline they download the selected resources. The videos are in M3U8 files (one M3U8 for the list of versions, one M3U8 file per version, then multiple video parts per version).

For those not familiar with the nuances: Meteor/cordova serves content from a local web server rather than `file://`.

What I've tried

1. `cdvfile:///` - got `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`
2. `file:///` - got `Not allowed to load local resource`
3. 'http://localhost/...` - no error, just doesn't load. Presumably the web server running in meteor/cordova isn't accessible
4. service workers - requests to load a service worker are blocked by cordova.
5. `blob:` for the M3U8 file, then `file://` inside that - didn't work, no errors.

I'm completely stumped - has anyone had success playing offline media in a meteor/cordova app?